# On closing questions and questions per day // Über Fragenschließen und Fragen pro Tag

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

## A friendly reminder that closing questions does not count against the question per day count

A few days or weeks ago I received a comment that we should be less zealous about closing questions if we ever wanted to pass the ten questions a day criterion laid out for graduation. My personal thought on that was ‘I would rather wait longer for graduation but graduate with good content’, but I do realise that that is little more of an opinion.

But the question whether closing questions excessively would negatively influence our question per day count kept bugging me so I turned to [Area 51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5491). I found an [answer there by Shog9](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10420) which read:

> No, the stats don't exclude closed questions. Obviously if you're closing enough questions for this to matter that's somewhat concerning, but still: you should focus on doing what's right for the site and its membership, not the number.

So please do not hold back with closing translation requests or general reference questions — it does not negatively affect our question per day count but helps keep the content here high-quality.

## Eine freundliche Erinnerung, dass geschlossene Fragen nicht gegen uns die Fragen-pro-Tag-Metrik eingehen.

Vor einigen Tagen oder Wochen hat mir jemand einen Kommentar hinterlassen, dass wir weniger eifrig beim Schließen von Fragen sein sollten, falls wir jemals das Kriterium der zehn Fragen pro Tag für die Graduierung erreichen wollen. Mein erster Gedanke dazu war »ich würde lieber später aber dafür mit besserem Inhalt graduieren«, aber mir ist klar, dass das weniger mehr als eine Meinung ist.

Die Frage, ob exzessives Schließen unsere Fragen-pro-Tag-Statistik negativ beeinflussen würde, hat mich aber nicht losgelassen, also habe ich [Area 51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5491) befragt. Dort habe ich eine [Antwort von Shog9](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10420) gefunden, die oben zitiert ist und sich folgendermaßen übersetzen lässt:

> Nein, die Statistiken rechnen geschlossene Fragen nicht heraus. Offensichtlich ist es zu einem gewissen Teil bedenklich, wenn ihr ausreichend Fragen schließen müsst, damit das eine Rolle spielt, aber dennoch: Ihr solltet euch darauf konzentrieren, was für die Seite und ihre Benutzer gut ist, nicht auf die Zahl.

Also bitte haltet euch nicht zurück, wenn Übersetzungsanfragen oder Grammatikbuchnachschlagfragen geschlossen werden sollen – es beeinflusst unsere Fragen-pro-Tag-Statistik nicht negativ, hilft aber, die Qualität des Inhalts zu erhalten.

Answer (score 1):

> Also bitte haltet euch nicht zurück, wenn Übersetzungsanfragen oder Grammatikbuchnachschlagfragen geschlossen werden sollen – es beeinflusst unsere Fragen-pro-Tag-Statistik nicht negativ, hilft aber, die Qualität des Inhalts zu erhalten.

Keine Sorge, ich halte mich da nicht zurück - nur nicht so, wie Du es Dir offenbar vorstellst: Diese Fragen bekommen von mir ein "Leave Open"-Votum, wann immer ich sie in der Review-Queue entdecke und ich ein Anzeichen dafür sehe, dass die Fragen aus Sicht eines Lernenden möglicherweise nicht so einfach mit Wörter- und Grammatikbüchern zu beantworten sind. Wenn man weiß, wo man nachschauen muss, sehen diese Fragen einfach aus - aber eben nur dann.

Und indirekt beeinflusst ein schnelles Schließen solcher Fragen unsere Fragen-pro-Tag-Statistik durchaus: Die Wahrscheinlichkeit ist ziemlich hoch, dass jemand, der sich auf diese Weise einmal abgekanzelt gefühlt hat, nicht mehr wieder kommt, um seine zweite, dritte, vierte Frage zu stellen, obwohl diese dann, da er in der Zwischenzeit hoffentlich schon mehr gelernt hat, durchaus auch interessanter sein könnten.

Comment: Ein wenig möchte ich daran erinnern, dass sich die Seite mit den *finer points* auseinandersetzen möchte.

Comment: @Jan Du verlinkst doch so gerne auf die [Tour]? (Was ich gut finde!): "German Language and Usage is a bilingual question-and-answer site for speakers of all levels who want to share and increase their knowledge of the German language." Wo steht da noch was von den "finer points"?

Comment: 100% meine Meinung. Wir sind nicht nur für Spezialisten, sondern auch für Lernende, was man an den Themen, die hier gefragt werden, ganz gut sehen kann.

Comment: Siehe auch http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/696/refining-community-moderation-on-closing-question